# Using the equivalent to the SQL IN function with LINQ with a collection

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

How do I translate the following in LINQ?

```
SELECT DISTINCT w.Worker_ID, w.Surname, w.FirstName, ps.JobNumber
FROM Worker w, ProjectSignatory ps
where w.Worker_ID = ps.Worker_ID
and ps.JobNumber 
IN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT pa.JobNumber
    FROM Worker w, PAAFRegister pa
    where w.Worker_ID = pa.Worker_ID
    and w.Worker_ID = @UserX)
```

I have seen anumber of posts which sugges that the .Contains function is a good idea, however since I am looking through a collection of results then based from what I have seen on other responses LINQ does not like it when people call .Contains on a collection.

I am trying to understand the workings of LINQ on the whole.  I am relatively inexperienced.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I have seen a few approaches and I am wondering if the following is a good start or would it be best achieved using a linge query using joins?

```
var sig = from w in db.Workers
          join ps in db.ProjectSignatories
              on w.Worker_ID equals ps.Worker_ID
          select ps;

var paaf = from w in db.Workers
           join pa in db.PAAFRegisters
               on w.Worker_ID equals pa.Worker_ID
           where w.Worker_ID == workerID
           select w;
```

I am aware that this is incomplete and seves no purpose or makes no sense to what I am attempting to achieve.  This was merely an example based on previous posts I have seen and wondering if the approach is suitable.

Thanks!

Comment: What evidence do you have of "LINQ does not like it when people call .Contains on a collection"? Have you *tried* it?

Comment: Evidently you have taken the time to consider what I am asking, here is he answer to your question.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4513454/how-to-translate-sql-where-expr-in-query-into-linq

Comment: I don't see how that question (where the answer was to use Contains, and it worked correctly) answers my question of what evidence you have for it *not* working.

Comment: Forgive my idiocy, :-) is does not!  However, the post that was one click further back on my browser window does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2066084/in-operator-in-linq

Comment: @Jon Skeet Quote "Since the return of the subquery is not a single string but a collection of strings I can't use the String.Contains() method."  Or have I not fully understood the context in that requirement.  Please correct accordingly!

Comment: You don't *want* to use `String.Contains`. You want to use `Contains` on the *collection*. Note that the question where the OP says it doesn't work is using the Entity Framework, which I believe is pickier than LINQ to SQL. Again: *have you tried it*?

Comment: Apologies, the answer is no however I understand what you are saying and I will give it a shot.  I am still getting to grips .Net technologies and SQL etc.  Are you the same John Skeet as in http://www.manning.com/skeet2/ this was mentioned as a good source here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4333689/beginner-book-for-lambda-expression.  I don't understand the lambda exoression use either.  Perhaps I should think a little bit more and try to understand more about what it is that I am asking.

Comment: Just looked at your profile and answered my own question.  I will certainly follow your instruction and give it a shot.  (More reading required) :-)

Answer (score 5):

You're looking for the `.Contains()` function.

1. First build up the inner filter set section of the query.

   E.G.: The part that goes in the `.Contains()` (in SQL terms the  "`ps.JobNumber IN (...)`" )
2. Filter your query by the new data subset by using the `.Contains` function.

**Example:**

C# SQL-like syntax:

```
var subSet = select JobNumber 
               from Workers 
              where Worker_ID == "UserX";

var result = select JobNumber 
               from Workers 
              where subSet.Contains(jobnumber);
```

LINQ chaining:

```
var subSet = Workers.Where(o => o.Worker_ID == "UserX")
                    .Select(o => o.JobNumber)
                    .Distinct();

var result = Workers.Where(o => subSet.Contains(o.JobNumber)).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you for your post, I also do not understand the lamda expression.  This is pretty basic I expect?  I have had no exposure to it, but I will do more reading and try to understand as oppose to blindly implementing the solution.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

You can create subselect's in LINQ.

```
var jobNumbers = select JobNumber from Workers where <your criteria, joins>
var myResult = select JobNumber from Workers where <your criteria, joins> and jobNumbers.Contains(JobNumber)
```

Comment: Thank you for your post.  I am going to try and understand a few things first before marking an answer that is most suited to my question situation.